# How do I run a foreach field in a class/ struct in matlab?

Tags: class, matlab, struct, foreach

This is my class : (direction) :

```
classdef direction
    properties
        up    = zeros(4,5)
        down  = zeros(4,5)
        left  = zeros(4,5)
        right = zeros(4,5)
    end

    %%% 
    methods

    end
end
```

I want to be able to run a 
for each field in 'direction'
do something
but I don't know how to use it.

Now I'm using 
`ROAD.up = ...`
but I'll want more fields at the end (16 or 32)

I try now a struct solution :
I'm using at the moment at

```
road(1).direction
```

and etc 
but I find the class solution more right...

Comment: Can you elaborate what you plan to do? Especially - is your problem to loop over all properties or over the array for one property?

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is you might be interested in [`structfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/structfun.html)

Theoretically it should work with classes as well - practically I find matlab classes unpredictable.

Comment: I would expect `structfun` to work as long as `fieldnames` returns the properties you're interested in.

Comment: It will not. `Structfun` requires an actual struct and will error if you pass it an object.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `properties` and loop over them:

```
d = direction
p = properties(d)
for k = 1:length(p)
  prop = p{k};
  d.(prop) = k
end
```

For example, the above code would start with:

```
d = 
  direction
Properties:
   up: [4x5 double]
 down: [4x5 double]
 left: [4x5 double]
right: [4x5 double]
```

and result in:

```
d = 
  direction
Properties:
   up: 1
 down: 2
 left: 3
right: 4
```

If you want to specify the list yourself, you can use a cell array of strings and use the `obj.('name')` operator:

```
p = {'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'};
k = 2; % Have a loop here instead
d.(p{k}) = 5; % Set property value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own function that applies functions to object fields, analagous to `structfun`.

```
function out = objfieldfun(x, fcn)
%OBJFIELDFUN Apply a function to every field of an object
out = x;
fields = fieldnames(x);
for iX = 1:numel(x)
    for iField = 1:numel(fields)
        out(iX).(fields{iField}) = feval(fcn, x(iX).(fields{iField}));
    end
end
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
d = direction;
d2 = objfieldfun(d, @(x)x+2);
```

But... usually objects' named properties have particular meanings and roles, and it'd be unusual to apply the same operation to all fields. Maybe it would make more sense to stash the similar properties inside a struct which itself is in a field on the object.